# Mixing variadic template values and variadic deduced types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Is the following perfectly defined by the standard ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int... Values, class... Types>
void f(Types&&... values)
{
    std::cout<<sizeof...(Values)<<" "<<sizeof...(Types)<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f<7, 5>(3);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles well under `g++ 4.8` but I wonder if it is normal.

Comment: Well I am not good at throwing around standard paragraphs, but why would you not expect that to work? Integrals are valid template parameter values, and type deduction from the arguments is there also for a very long time.

Comment: As your `Types` are deduced from your function parameters, and your `Values` are specified explicitly, and since `5` is most-definitely *not* a *type*, I have a hard time seeing how this doesn't compile exactly as you have specified (and expected) it should. What would you expect may be a concern of non-standard-compliance?

Comment: [temp.param]/11 "A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the *parameter-type-list*
of the function template or has a default argument" So I'd say it's legal unless `Types` only appears in non-deduced contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ISO C++ standard's current working draft](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) 14.1 (11):

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template >parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list of >the function template or has a default argument

In your case 'Types' is a *function parameter pack* and 'Values', that is a *template parameter pack*, can be always followed by a *function parameter pack*.
Also this code works for the same reason:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Values, class... Types>
void f(Types&&... values)
{
    std::cout<<sizeof...(Values)<<" "<<sizeof...(Types)<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f<int, float>(-3, 5);
    return 0;
}
```